# How to open facebook app user-timeline page for a specific id from my android app?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to open facebook app for a specific user profile. 
This is my code for opening the facebook intent:

```
 try{
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), 
                    facebook_id, 
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("fb://profile/" + facebook_id));
            startActivity(intent);

            }catch(Exception e){

            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.facebook.com/UserNamePage")));
            }
```

This is how I received the user_id:

```
user.getId();
```

(The user is a GraphUser object from facebook sdk) Is this the correct way to get the user id and use it for openning the inetnt? Because this is not worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Graph API 2.x, then the user ID you have is an app-scoped user id, and there's no support for getting to a user profile from an app-scoped id in the Facebook app.